# how to automate timed running of 2 programs?

Tags: linux, timer, fedora, running-other-programs

I'm working in linux. I have two programs that run for infinite time ( that is , wont stop unless i kill the process ).i want to run program 1 first and then run program 2 after 20 seconds ( both will have to run simultaneously as one reads a file written by the other ).Currently , i am running the 2 programs by manually keeping track of time.. Is there a way to automate this ? i.e. is there any command or can any program be written to do this..

Comment: If your synchronization needs are crude, then this will be sufficient.  If your producer and consumer may be long-running, or may operate at different rates, however, I suspect a more advanced solution will be required.

Comment: consumer and producer run at same rates .

Comment: I'm curious, how do you know?

Comment: i assume they run at same rates becaue i set the timers with the same interval in both , and anyway , i just need crude synchronization for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prog1 &
sleep 20
prog2
```

Comment: the 2 programs are : first_auto.c and after 20 seconds , prime_auto.c
how do i compile and run.. can you please explain..

Comment: @trinity:  That's a different question.  Please ask a new question.

Comment: If you don't know how to compile your programs, that's something you should research first.

Comment: Huh! trinity - the trinity that hacked the IRS database....quote from the Matrix....

Comment: @Greg and @Tyler : till then i thought i had to use ./a.out for both programs and hence the doubt.. Now i found out i could save the out files using the -o option.
@Anon : Thanks a lot

Comment: @trinity:  You also have the option to rename them via `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the shell:

$ program1 & sleep 20 ; program2

Answer (score 0):

If one program reads from the file output by the other you should consider using a pipe to pass output from one to the input of the other:

`$> program1 | program2`

I'm assuming that you have control over these two programs and can get them to write to `stdout` and read from `stdin`.

Comment: Actually , i maintain a circular buffer of files - f1 , f2 , f3.. and the first program writes into these files , switching between them every 20 seconds. And the reader program also reads from these. I have   written the code to do this and it works fine..